# add numeric properties to node via REST

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to add notes with non-string properties via the REST interface?
I'm using neo4j-spatial for my application and it requires the lat and lon properties to be numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to put a numeric in the JSON. So if you want to put those, just send in:

```
{
    "lat": 52.6234,
    "lon": 15.1231
}
```

Comment: integers won't work for me. But a cypher query does the job. Can you send integers in json without being interpreted as a string?